# ! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `d'

Tags: tables, errors

I have two tables in an article written by somebody else which compiles fine with TeXLive 2013, but after an upgrade to the 2015 version xelatex hangs at them. Pressing enter the file still compiles and looks fine on first view, just I'm wondering what the `d` option is/was, if I can just delete it, or if I would be missing something. The table environment starts `\begin{table}[htdp]`. If I get it right, `h` means to place it where it has been defined, `t` means the top of the page, `p` means that it should have a page of its own (which the second table, 15 rows long, doesn't have), but so far I didn't find a `d` option of floats.

Comment: I do not know it. Maybe something custom. The only parameter which is missing here is `b` for bottom. Just delete all of them and see, where it floats. You may adapt that behaviour later on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there isn't any float option `d`.  however, until the version of latex on tex live 2015, unknown options were simply ignored.

effective with tex live 2015, options are checked and unknown ones are flagged as errors.

Comment: Where did you learn this? ;-)

Comment: @egreg -- it was in (i think) frank's discussion.  *somebody* mentioned it this afternoon.